# Compling tesseract 4 gives fatal error in ubuntu 16 64 bit

Tags: make, configure, compiler

I installed leptonica 1.74 successfully from source. After that, I am trying to compile tesseract 4 from source (tar) on my ubuntu 16.04 64 bit machine.

But I m not able to move forward bcz of this error. Please help me to find the error.

config.log file here https://pastebin.com/UVYbqN1h

terminal text here https://pastebin.com/YJ6S4Egg

I am failing at sudo make step.

Please help and say where im doing mistake.